# URL for API call in Angular service doesn't resolve correctly in test server

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 5 app with a .NET Core REST Api back end - all part of the same project.

I published to a test server and it all worked fine. All the calls to the API from my services resolved correctly. I then implemented a Login service which works fine in my dev machine but the URL does not resolve correctly in the test server.

In the test server, the url resolves to *[Machine Name]/api/auth/login* instead of *[Machine Name]/[App Name]/api/auth/login*

All the services are defined in the providers array exclusively in app.module.ts and I can find no difference between the Login service and the others.

I got around the problem by using *Location.prepareExternalUrl* but I want to know why that was necessary. None of the other service calls to the api need that and they all still work fine.

Login service:

```
login(userName: string, password: string) {

    return this.httpClient.post<Token>(this.location.prepareExternalUrl('/api/auth/login'), { userName, password }).pipe(
        tap(res => this.setSession(res))
    ).shareReplay();
}
```

Companies service as an example:

```
getAll(): Observable<Company[]> {

    return this.httpClient.get<Company[]>('api/companies');

}
```

Comment: What is the base ref set as in the html? Are you using the Angular CLI to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all other services are working fine, looks to me, caused by a leading slash `/` before the login URL, which will treat the URL as an absolute URL from the server root and that's why the application's context path **AppName** is not part of the URL.

I generally use the following approach for the api URLs in my services.

```
`${environment.BASE_API_URL}/someService/`
```

Then define the environment specific `BASE_API_URL` in the `environment.*.ts` files. This also allows me to change the api url at one place and point to a different environment, e.g. `BASE_API_URL: 'http://localhost:8080/api'` would now point to the api deployed on my localhost@8080.

Also make sure your `base href` in the `index.html` is correctly defined as per the angular documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#set-the-base-href) for relative URLs

Comment: It was the damn slash! Thanks.